# Using PHP to send data to another page after already receiving data from a page

Tags: php, html, forms

What I am trying to do is: after sending data from form.php to data_received.php, I want data_received.php to send it to pdf.php without the user having to fill out another form. Is that possible?

Here is something

Form example for form.php

```
<form action="data_received.php" method="post">

<div data-for="date">
                        <label>Date</label>
                        <input type="text" name="date">
                    </div>
<div data-for="time">
                        <label>Time</label>
                        <input type="text" name="time">
                    </div>
```

data_received.php:

```
<?php
$date = $_POST['date'];
$time = $_POST['time'];
echo '$date';
echo '$time';
?>
<button onclick="window.location.href = 'pdf.php';">Print to pdf </button>
<button onclick="windoe.location.href = 'form.php';>Back</button>
```

I just want to know how to get the user's answer of $date and $time to pdf.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution Here !!!

form.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Log-in</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="header">
    <h1>Log-in</h1>
</div>

<form action="data_received.php" method="post">

<div data-for="date">
                        <label>Date</label>
                        <input type="text" name="date">
                    </div>
<div data-for="time">
                        <label>Time</label>
                        <input type="text" name="time">
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" name="register_btn" class="Register"></td>
</body>
</html>
```

data_received.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Log-in</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(window).on('load', function() {
    window.open("pdf.php", "pdf", "height=400,width=400");
    })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="header">
    <h1>Log-in</h1>
</div>

<form >
   <?php
session_start();
$date = $_POST['date'];
$time = $_POST['time'];
$_SESSION["date"] = $_POST['date'];
$_SESSION["time"] = $_POST['time'];
echo $date;
echo '<br/>';
echo $time;
?>
<br/>
<input type="Button" value="Back" onclick="windoe.location.href ='form.php';">
<input type="Button" value="Print to pdf " onclick="window.location.href = 'pdf.php';">

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

pdf.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Log-in</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="header">
    <h1>PDF</h1>
</div>
<form method="post" >
    <?php
    session_start();
    ?>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Date:</td>
            <td><input type="text"  value="<?PHP if(isset($_SESSION['date'])){echo $_SESSION['date'];}?>"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Time:</td>
            <td><input type="text" value="<?PHP if(isset($_SESSION['time'])){echo $_SESSION['time'];}?>"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="Button" value="Close" onclick="self.close();"> </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution Here !!!
i have planed for your doubt, i hope its useful for you.

[image]

Comment: Yeah thanks Uday it is helpful, it shows what I want, but I need the code that makes it retrieve. Also what is Page load() and Call pdf.php() doing

Comment: please post your sample code  then only i'm able to do this job ,

Comment: You should update your answer to add a code sample as in it current state it does not answer the question